# Can every elementary set in $ \mathbb{R^n} $ be written as almost disjoint union of cubes

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

I was wondering if every elementary set in $ \mathbb{R^n} $ can be written as almost disjoint union of cubes.
I know that we can write any elementary set as disjoint union of cuboids and that we can write any open set in $ \mathbb{R^n} $ as a union of almost disjoint closed cubes.
So I guess the problem really breaks down to showing that every cuboid can be written as an almost disjoint union of cubes. Probably I am missing something very simple. Any help would be very much appreciated.

An elementary set $E$ is defined as $ E = \bigcup_{k=1}^{z} A_k $ with the sets $ A_k $ being cuboids (The union needs to be finite). A cuboid is the cartesian product of intervals. $A_k = I_1 \times ... \times I_n $. A cuboid is a cube if the length of each interval is the same i.e. $|I_1| = ... = |I_n| $ for $I_i = (a_i, b_i)$ we define $ |I_i| $ as  $ |I_i| = b_i - a_i$. A union is said to be almost disjoint if the inner parts of each set in the union are disjoint.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Would you mind defining "elementary set"? What do you mean by "almost disjoint union"? Cube = product of closed, bounded intervals?

Comment: @Ulli I added further clarifications

Comment: Is it the **definition** of an elementary set that it can be written as the finite union of cuboids? Are infinite unions allowed?

Comment: By interval, you mean *open*, bounded interval? Allowing the empty set?

Comment: @PaulFrost they have to be finite

Comment: @Ulli by interval I mean any type of interval that is bounded. It does not have to be open. The empty set is allowed

Comment: So, $(0, 1) \times [4, 5] \times (6, 7] $ is a cube? I.e., $|I|$ is analogously defined for all types of bounded interval?

Comment: And please don't forget to answer Paul Frost's question whether the above is the **definition** of elementary set. Or better, clarify this in the question.

Comment: @Ulli yes this would be a cube. Yes it is the definition of an elementary set

Comment: "any open set in $ \mathbb{R^n} $ as a union of almost disjoint closed cubes" - so in this case you must allow infinite unions. Please clarify in which cases the unuion must be finite and in which case it is allowed to be infinite.

Comment: @PaulFrost every open set in $ \mathbb{R^n} $ can be written as infinite union of almost disjoint closed cubes. However, any elementary set can be written as finite union of (almost)disjoint cuboids.